# svn revert with correct svn blame

Tags: svn

Is there a way of using svn revert to go back to a previous state of particular file, while simultaneously keeping correct author information (so that the author displayed is the one who made the original change, rather than the one doing the revert) in svn blame?

Comment: "svn revert" just changes the local copy.  Do you mean that you are reverting to an earlier copy and then committing?

Comment: Well, that's the only way I know of reverting - I was hoping there was some other way that would avoid subvesion assuming I had just re-committed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion maintains a history of the project in the server.  That history is meant to be immutable, what happened in the past will remain in the server.  So, "reverting" a repository isn't really undoing the past, it is replacing the "current" copies with an older copy of the files.  After you revert, you must commit the change to go forward.

This means that if you "commit" older files, the svn blame information will be those of the person committing.  If you want that information to be different, you will have to either:

1. Create an environment where you can submit as the correct person.
2. Modify a past commit to set the information as you would like it.

Note that the actual person who created the old revision of the files didn't create them in the current context, so they won't be the person to break the build if you decide to "revert" files to the state in which they wrote them a few days / weeks / months ago.  In reality, **you** will be the person who broke the build, and therefore the correct person to blame.

That said, if you find the benefits of directing the blame elsewhere outweigh the added confusion, to do #1 you have a few options.  The easiest is to setup a bunch of user accounts on the SVN server accessible via SSH.  Since you control the accounts, you can ssh to any particular user.  Since you are going to checkout and update without knowledge of the user's svn password, you need to use file URLs, which bypass either the HTTP / HTTPS / SVN+SSH password checking.  Since you have sufficent permissions to do all of this, you will be able to add such users to the group accessing the actual SVN repositories.

To do #2, you have to get familiar with SVN's internal architecture of storing the log properties; but to be quite honest with you, I'm not sure if it is fully achievable.  I suspect it would start with a deeper inspection of

```
svn propedit -r N --revprop svn:author authorName URL
```